# I'm trying to get the Debug.Log to detect a collision when I bring two objects together

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

When I put this script into the object, a cube, it does not register the platform it hits beneath when I make the gameObject the platform. I'm trying to get the two objects to detect collision between each other but it does not seem to work. Neither objects are trigger checked in the Box Colliders. The cube has a rigid body with gravity checked but the platform does not. This is a 3D game.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Collision : MonoBehaviour

{
public Transform gameObject;


void onCollisionEnter(Collision col)
 {
  if (col.gameObject);
    {
    Debug.Log("Yes");
    }
 } 
}
```

Comment: Change onCollisionEnter to OnCollisionEnter.

Answer (score 1):

As Sven Viking already said, you have to change the syntax from onCollisionEnter to OnCollision enter. Also, let's take a look at your logic:

You want to check that, if your cube object collides with another object, and if that object is the same as the one you're referencing, you want to see a log of that in your console. Currently, however, you're asking for something else.

First of all, your platform is not stored as a gameObject, it's stored as a *Transform*. Those two are different things, the Transform stores the position/rotation/scale of an object, while 'GameObject' is the entire object, includng its Transform. Also, you named your variable gameObject, which you should never do - Never name variables with the same name as existing elements.

'col' represents the collision. col.gameObject is the gameObject of that collision. There's no logic demanded there. You're just making a reference. What you want, instead, is compare the gameObject of the collision with your referenced gameObject(the platform) and, if both of them are the same, then you can proceed. Therefore, what you want is:

```
public class CollisionScript : MonoBehaviour

{
public GameObject platform;


void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
 {
  if (col.gameObject == platform);
    {
    Debug.Log("Yes");
    }
 } 
}
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

EDIT: I see now you also named your class 'Collision', which I'm pretty sure would break things, as Collision is already a class within Unity(you can check that looking at "Collision col", that indicates there is a class named Collision). You should change both the class name on the top of the script and the file name to reflect that change.